# Did I normalize correctly?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, normalization, database-normalization

[image: user view]

Doing some practice questions and just wanted to know if I normalized correctly. Thanks.

#### Un-normalized Table

```
INVOICE [Invoice#(pk), InvoiceDate, Sales, Cust#,
          (EquipClass, EquipClassDesc, Equip#, EquipDesc, EquipCharge, EquipQTY)]
```

#### 1NF Tables

```
INVOICE [Invoice#(pk), InvoiceDate, Sales, Cust#]
Equipment [ Invoice#(pk), Equip#,(pk), EquipClass, EquipClassDesc,
            EquipDesc, EquipCharge, EquipQTY)]
```

#### 2NF Tables

```
INVOICE [Invoice#(pk), InvoiceDate, Sales, Cust#]
Equipment [Equip#,(pk), EquipClass, EquipClassDesc, EquipDesc, EquipCharge]
INVOICE_Equipment [Invoice#(pk) (FK), Equip# (pk) (FK), EquipQTY]
```

#### 3NF Tables

```
INVOICE [Invoice#(pk), InvoiceDate, Salesperson#(fk)]
Salesperson [Salesperson#(pk), SalespersonName]
Invoice_SalesPerson [Invoice#(pk)(fk), Salesperson#(pk)(fk), Cust#]
Equipment [Equip#,(pk), EquipClass(fk), EquipDesc, EquipCharge,]
Equipment_Class [EquipClass(pk), EquipClassDesc]
INVOICE_Equipment [Invoice#(pk) (FK), Equip# (pk) (FK), EquipQTY]
```

Comment: You may be able to read the image; I'm antique and it is far too small (and clicking on it doesn't lead to a readable image) so it is of negative help to me for understanding your problem.  You should identify the functional dependencies; those will control whether your analysis is plausible.

Comment: For various reasons, you shouldn't use an invoice number as a PK. I would make this unique and use a surrogate key instead.

Comment: As Jonathan said, write out your functional dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the Unnormalized, 1NF and 2NF tables never mention a sales person, there's no basis for the splits and additions that occur as you progress from 2NF to 3NF in the prior schemas.

Additionally, an invoice is more probably associated with a customer and a salesperson directly (it would have independent FK references to the customer table (which isn't identified in the schema) and the salesperson table).  The Invoice_SalesPerson table looks spurious, and the removal of customer number from Invoice looks dubious.  It could be done the way you've shown, but I'd never mark it as correct without a clear, verbose, cogent explanation of why that was necessary (and I'd still be sceptical that it was not necessary).